ros c_cpp_properties.json path is not a directory
i'm editing my file c_cpp_properties.json in order to add elements in includePath[].
Even if the path exists, i got this error (https://i.sstatic.net/1KPUmjI3.png)
I use vscode on ubuntu20.04.
Does anybody know how to solve?
i just check if the path really exists.
